# Работа с gprs-модемом через Delphi

Tags: gprs, delphi, модемы

Добрый день друзья! Мне дали на работе задание разработать программу, которая будет взаимодействовать с gprs-модемом, передавать и принимать значения от технических устройств, также подключенных через gprs-модемы, но удаленно, через провайдер связи, после чего программа должна записывать в БД данные полученные от удаленного оборудования.

Вот схема примерной работы всей системы:
[image]

Основная задача разработать программу по приему и отсылке gprs-данных. Сначала программа делает запрос через gprs-модем или телефон к удаленному модему чтобы связаться с оборудованием. Например, команда получить температуру нагревательного прибора, после оборудование отвечает на команду, передает параметр температуры и посылает обратно через gprs-модемы программе. Программа это значение сохраняет в базе данных. Посоветуйте ссылками, советами, исходниками, как такое разработать. Я так понимаю что нужно работать с сокетами и `ip`-адресами здесь чтобы достичь желаемого...

Основные вопросы какие приходят на ум:

1. как установить программно `GPRS` Соединение?
2. как программно разорвать модемное соединение?
3. как программно передать и принять gprs-данные?

Comment: Помогите с этим вопросом. Не могу найти в инете информации. Делфисты отзовитесь.

Answer (score 2):

1-2. Вопрос решен `2г назад. Написана утилита, позволяющая контролировать сетевое подключение (испытано на MTC и Velcom). Только место GPRS модем - компьютер используется 3G
модем.
 3. Вопрос решается сейчас (и удачно) - опрос удаленных счетчиков расхода (жидкость,газ,тепловая и электроэнергия и пр.). Проблемы только в знании протокола обмена с  "Оборудование". 
  Не каждый GPRS модем в "Оборудование - GPRS модем" годен для этой цели. 
 Утилиту могу выслать. При запуске ее программно, с указанием handle окна, она передает (SendMessage) в это окно всю необходимую информацию. Надо ее только найти. Объем не позволяет ответить на вопросы. Поэтому - multisoft@rambler.ru
подробнее.

Comment: Как сказал заказчик, ему нужна самописная программа, так как не устраивают программы, которые выполняют аналогичные задачи. Хотя пообщаться с вами по ящику я готов. Напишу письмо.